# get the href value from selected option and change the href of the button

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to get the href value of the selected option so that i can now go to the link that i selected using the button.

Here's my code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="soa">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Choose the name of student</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"><span
                               class="text-danger"></span> Name of Student</label> 
                            <select name="childNames" class="form-control input-lg" id="childNames" data-size="5">
                               <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                               <option value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/billsandpayments/invoice">John Dela Cruz</option>
                               <option value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/billsandpayments/invoice1">Josh Dela Cruz </option>
                               <option value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/billsandpayments/invoice2">Jane Dela Cruz</option>
                            </select>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href=''><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">View</button></a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where are `href` attributes of the option tags..?

Comment: Hi Checkout this fiddle like : https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/254gtrcc/1/

Comment: just remove the button (<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">) and style the link(<a href=''>) as a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a id to =>

```
<a id="link" href=''><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">View</button></a>
```

This should work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#childNames").on('change', function () {

                var ref = document.getElementById("childNames").value;
                alert(ref);
                $('#link').attr('href', ref);

    });

});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/b20ng5a6/)

Comment: Hi Sir, I applied it, but when i click the view button, it still go to the current page

Comment: can in inspect elements in browser go see if the reference is changed or put a alert to see if you are getting the correct  reference

Comment: the href value of the view button still null

Comment: have you added a JQuery library ? if not add it i will change answer according to it

Comment: I add this 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#childNames").on('change', function () {

            var ref = document.getElementById("childNames").value;

            document.getElementById('link').href = ref;
        });
  </script>

Comment: Sir, still doesn't change the href value of view. I already update my script :(

Comment: ok for my knowledge (and i have tested out this ) the code is working ..only explanation is you have not added a JQuery library to work this , so download put JQuery and put it on top of html documet <script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Do i need to indicate the <a href="(link)"></a> in the select option?

Comment: mmmm you dont need to do that ... but check if your links works and add JQuery library

Answer (score 0):

Here's also the alternative answer. Just add it to your script

```
     <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $("#childNames").change(function () {
                        var ref =$(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
                        $('#link').attr('href', ref);

            });

        });
     </script>
```